# GIT - Hello world!

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push

Может кто подсказать как работать с GIT ? Для работы с ним поставил себе TurtoiseGIT.

1. Есть проект(папка) с единственным файлом - Hello.txt.
2. Создаю репозиторий GIT в этой папке(Create GIT repository here, папка расшарена).
3. Делаю Commit, добавляя в созданный репозиторий единственный файл - hello.txt, с текстом - Hello world!
4. Клонирую себе этот проект в свой локальный репозиторий
5. В своём локальном(клонированном) репозитории изменяю текст единственного файла, на "Hello World again!" и делаю Commit на локальный репозиторий.
6. Пытаюсь отправить изменения в главный репозиторий -(Push в Origin) и вылетает ошибка: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master

Что я сделал не так ? 
1. Как отправить изменившейся файл в удалённый репозиторий с TurtoiseGIT ?

Comment: а где храниться ваш удаленный репозиторий?

Comment: На диске D:\Repo, локальный на диске C:\Repo

Comment: обычно удаленным репозиторием называют репозиторий на другом компьютере. у вас как я понял оба репозитория находятся на одном компьютере?

Comment: Да. Всё верно. К ней(к главному репозиторию) будет открыт сетевой доступ, или она будет перемещена на сервер.

Answer (score 2):

В самом начале Вы сделали большую ошибку - поставили TurtoiseGIT. Сносите. Оно не нужно.

Поставьте нормальный, правильный гит с официального сайта https://git-scm.com/

Так как Вы делаете два репозитория, никто обычно не делает.

Существуют два типа репозитория - обычный и голый (bare). В Вашем случае нужен один bare репозиторий и один и более обычных. На "сервере"  (это может быть диск D на этой же машине) создаете bare репу

```
git init --bare
```

Bare репозиторий не имеет рабочего каталога (working dir) и в нем "коммить" нельзя (точнее можно, но не так просто).

Все. теперь переходим к обычному рабочему каталогу, который клонируете через clone

```
git clone "D:\Repo\"
```

(или как там у Вас с путями). Теперь можно спокойно создавать файлы, коммитить и пушить. Все будет работать.

Теперь можно склонировать репозиторий ещё куда-нибудь и работать там себе в параллель.

То есть, если Вам нужна классическая схема сервер и клиенты, то Вам нужен один bare репозиотрий.

Но что, если все таки хочется "запушить" в "не bare" репу? В этом случае обычно применяют обратный процесс - pull  с другой стороны. То есть, если A хочет запушить B, то нужно делать наоборот - B пуллит изменения от A.

> К ней(к главному репозиторию) будет открыт сетевой доступ

Так можно сделать. Более того, даже будет работать. Но лучше поднять себе любой гит сервер - будет надежнее. Если локальный нужен, то тут хорошо [gogs](https://gogs.io/).  Но никто не отменял gitlab/github.

Comment: TutoiseGIT работает через GIT с официального сайта. Без него он не работает. Так что надо сделать, что бы положить файл обратно - в главный репозитарии ?

Comment: Я все написал. Даже более, два варианта.

Comment: Я и другие пользователи не могут класть файлы этот вариант

Comment: Ваш мастер репозиторий должен быть bare

Comment: Минусанул за холиварное утверждение про TurtoiseGIT. Можно работать из консоли, можно из интерфейса - это дело вкуса.

Comment: Просто Вы никогда не натыкались на баги гуевых гит оберток.

Comment: KoVadim, да, так заработало. Спасибо.

Comment: Просто TurtoiseGIT выдавал сообщение красным цветом при создании bare-репозитория, и с самого начала я не понял и не рискнул туда нажимать.

Comment: Объясните это @Kromster :-)

Answer (score 0):

Получается, последовательность действий такая:

1. Создаём новый Bare-репозиторий(пустой, ставя галочку "Bare").
2. Клонируем этот пустой репозиторий к себе (git clone)
3. В него кладём нужные файлы и делаем Commit локальному репозиторию.
4. Что бы положить в "удалённый" репозиторий, делаем Push в Origin

Comment: Это вам понятно, что вы имели в виду под «делаем Push в Origin», а неопытному читателю не будет понятно.